# Replace letters with symbols java

Tags: java, replace, indexof

Making a hangman style of game

I have a random word and I would like to replace the letters of the word with an asterix `*` so that when the program starts the word is shown as `*****`.

I assume that when someone inputs a letter for the hangman game you get the index of that character in the word and then replace the corresponding `*`.

```
public class JavaApplication10 {

    public static String[] wordArray = new String[1];
    public static String file_dir = "Animals.txt";
    public static String selectedWord = "";
    public static char[] wordCharacter = new char[1];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        wordArray = get_word(file_dir);
        selectedWord = select_word(wordArray);

        System.out.println(selectedWord);
    }

    public static String[] get_word(String file_dir) throws IOException {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file_dir);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    }

    public static String select_word(String[] wordArray) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int lines = Math.abs(rand.nextInt(wordArray.length) - 1);
        return wordArray[lines];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Pshemo How do I replace selectedWord with the same amount of * as the length

Comment: There must be hundreds of examples of Hangman code out on the net if you search for them.

Comment: @Squonk trust me I have looked. There doesn't seem to be a place that clearly states what to do. All i seem to be able to find is other people asking the same question but the answers would not work on my code or I do not know how to make work for my code. I have only begun learning java within the last month.

Comment: why create an array of strings with a length of 1!!!? just have a simple reference to the object?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will resolve your problem:

```
StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(word);
for(int i=0; i<word.length ;i++) {
myName.setCharAt(i, '*');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String repeat(char ch, int count) {
    char[] arr = new char[count];
    Arrays.fill(arr, ch);
    return new String(arr);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(repeat('*', 10));
System.out.println(repeat('A', 15));
System.out.println(repeat('+', 13));
```

*Output*

```
**********
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+++++++++++++
```